# Reverse Proxy Configuration - Folder redirecting to original url

Tags: nginx, hosting, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have recently created a reverse proxy setup for our client, basically, we are a service provider which hosts static HTML files as a result of our tool.
Now the clients want an easy way for their users to access the contents and also benefit from SEO, so we choose a reverse-proxy approach.

**Client-Side looks like https://clientdomain.com/mycontent**

**Our domain is: https://staticfiles.com**

When we write *https://clientdomain.com/mycontent/foldername/*, our server correctly serves the index.html file from the server and the client is happy.

But the issue arises when we try to visit  *https://clientdomain.com/mycontent/foldername (without slash)*, our server gives a 301 response and redirects users to *https://staticfiles.com/foldername/ (with a slash)*

Any way to handle this through the Nginx config where before redirecting to folder notation, it checks the incoming host and then redirects it accordingly.

For proxy pass we are using the following config:

```
location  /mycontent {
    proxy_pass https://staticfiles.com/;
    proxy_redirect redirect replacement;
}
```

Comment: The reverse proxy should handle this automatically with the default settings for [`proxy_redirect`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) unless your `location` or `proxy_pass` settings are confusing it.

Comment: @RichardSmith Please check the above config, that is the one we are using for client-side for proxying.

Comment: The `location` value should have a trailing `/` for correct translation of the URI and `proxy_redirect redirect replacement;` appears to be a cut&paste from [the manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) and lacks any real values - it would probably work with the defaults (by deleting that statement altogether).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code snippet, when we tried to actually read the nginx docs in details, we found that it does not mean literally, but that the redirect URLs have to be provided here

```
proxy_redirect redirect replacement;
```

So this should actually have been

```
proxy_redirect https://staticfiles.com https://clientdomain.com/mycontent
```

What this will do is change all the instances of **https://staticfiles.com** to **https://clientdomain.com/mycontent** from any location headers received from the actual server.